# Statistical analysis of polygons QGIS : find areas of statistical difference

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics, statistics

I have polygons for the country divided into E.D. areas.

These polygons illustrate the average annual rainfall in their ED area.

Is there any way to statistically tell if one polygon area has a statistically higher or lower volume of rain compared to its surrounding areas?

or if I extract points from these polygons and make a smooth surface raster via interpolation - is there a way I can I assess my layer for statistically higher or lower rainfall ?

Comment: QGIS really isn't a statistical analyzing software. I suspect you would be better off extracting the rainfall data as a spreadsheet and calculating statistical significance outside of the GIS environment. If you need help with the mathematics of calculating statistical significance, that seems like a better question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi @csk thank you for your reply. I will post this question on cross validated.